# how to get array of sentences and words passing as parameter to a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a function say

```
 var init = function(data){
     all sentences: " I have to get all the sentences and return an array containing all sentences"
     all words : "this method should return an array of words in ‘Data’ when there is no parameter passed in. Optionally, when there is a parameter passed in that is a number, return the words in the sentence indicated by the input parameter"

     all reverse sentences: "this method is the same as all Sentences, except it should return the sentences in reverse order"

     reverse words :" same as all words but in reverse order"
     countWordsBeginningWith:" this method should return the amount of words that begin with an inputted string. The optional second parameter should determine what sentence the words come from when present."
```

thanks

Comment: What exactly are you asking to do here?

Comment: I have a similar kind of situation where I have to pass a complex object to my function ....I have a working code with me ...just want to see if I can optimize it.....@jnpcl this is not a homework (if you don't have any advice , please don't speak) ...in my situation i have to get a JSON object coming from the server and I have to access particular key from it and have to manipulate ..not worried about the JSON object but manipulating it efficiently is a problem...

Comment: @Paul - Your question sounds nothing like your comment. Just for the record.

Comment: @paul: Please do not tell people not to speak, jnpcl was asking a valid question. -1 for lip, and for a question that differs from your comment clarification entirely.

Comment: @Orbling - i agre with you the OP was not asking the question properly. that's all. +1

Comment: Great! instead of providing suggestion you guys argue on  how to ask question...anyways thanks for your valuable comments....@Orbling thanks for negative vote

Comment: @paul: No problem.  I do not down vote lightly, your conduct was not what we expect in the community - especially rolling back an edit that purely fixed layout to a broken variant.  If you have a sensible question then by all means state it, try not to withhold context and details otherwise it does not help answerers.

Comment: @Orbling I have used the community for long and never faced that kind of arguments. Its not what I expect instead of providing suggestion..for your record any question is relevant and instead of asking whether its your homework kind of things is not at all relevant in this context ...instead of wasting time I prefer should provide suggestion and if not shouldn't ask some irrelevant question which doesn't belongs to the context of the problem...

Comment: @paul: [Homework questions have a slightly different policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) to regular questions, and are supposed to be marked as such.  Answerers are expected to answer the questions slightly differently, guiding the student in the right direction rather than just answering the question fully.  For obvious reasons.  When questions look contrived, as in they are most likely exercises, it is standard practice to query that, in order that appropriate steps can be taken.

Comment: @paul: Also, what you prefer in the way of answers and comments is not entirely relevant either.  People choose to answer or comment as they see fit, providing they are polite you should respect that and act equally politely, answering their queries if possible.  After all, they are taking the time to assist your question.  Telling them to be quiet is bad form.  If you answered questions as much as asking them, you would probably respect that.

Comment: @Orbling ...thanks for letting me know about the policies...not aware of that...anyways lesson learned..

Comment: @paul: Good, I'm glad.  Apologies for any annoyance caused.

Comment: @Orbling...I should be the one apologies for my words...keep up the good work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to do is decompose your `argument` (assuming it's a string) into an `array`. For instance:

```
function getAllWords(sentences) {
    var result = sentences.split(' ');
    return result;
}

var init = function(data){
    var result = [];
    result['words'] = getAllWords(data.text);
    // result['sentences'] = getAllSentences(data.text);
    // result['sentencesreversed'] = getReverseSentences(data.text);
    // result['sentencewords'] = getReverseWords(data.text);
    // result['beginswith'] = getWordsBeginningWith(data.text, data.beginswith);
    return result;
}

var getIt = {
    'beginswith': 't',
    'text': 'This is stuff. I am a sentence. Stuff happens now.'
};

console.log(init(getIt));
```

This is a very simplistic answer, not taking into account for periods, commas, and other bits. But that's the general answer. Some `for loops` and/or `RegEx`'s may occur after this point, buyer beware.

Comment: @Paul - You might read here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html Objects and arrays are the same in Javascript, which is probably unusual. The notation used to reference them are interchangeable, and if not, I hope someone corrects me.

Comment: thanks for the link...for information objects and arrays are not same ...they are different primitives in JS...though you can loop through for in in array too like object literal..

Comment: **primitive, primitive value** - "JavaScript has 5 primitive datatypes: string, number, boolean, null, undefined"; **object** - "All objects are derived from Object, *including arrays*, and Object itself is also an object." - https://developer.mozilla.org/En/JS/Glossary

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can pass any data structure as a function parameter.

First learn how to construct an array of strings to contain you word or sentences. Once you have accomplished this it will be straightforward.